# active admin destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

im working in a project writen in ruby on rails and im currently using the active admin gem for its content manager system of my site im just wondering how active admin is using the delete action im trying to overide it but i my code doesent work, i think we are having a problem in how to get the specific line to be destroy

```
def destroy


  @menu = Menu.find(params[:menu_recipe][:menu_id])
  @menu_recipe = @menu.menu_recipes.find(params[:id])
  @menu_recipe.remove_recipe
  @menu_recipe.destroy
  redirect_to @reservation, :notice => "recipe destroyed"

      end
```

it comes with a error of

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `params[:menu_recipe]` is not set. Try putting `params[:menu_recipe] ||= {}` at the beginning.

But why is it that you're finding through the `Menu`, anyway? Can't you just do 'MenuRecipe.find(params[:id])'?

Comment: still the same or i didnt code it right can you please code where to put `params[:menu_recipe] ||= {}` im new in ruby on rails sorry.

Comment: First, see the edit I just made. If you do need to go through `Menu`, the line I put should go at the very beginning of the action. Note that you'll also have to be careful before doing `Menu.find(params[:menu_recipe][:menu_id])` since if the `params[:menu_recipe][:menu_id]` is nil, the find will raise an exception.

Comment: uhm yea i re-write my code with that and it worked thanks for the help :)